# How can we convert this if-statement to a "switch"

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

Say we have the following `if-statement`:

```
if (arg.compare("abc") == 0)
{
...
}
```

If I want to convert it to have a `switch` form, is the following correct?

```
switch (arg)
{
case "arg.compare("abc") == 0: cout<<"statements the same";
break;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: No. You cannot, unless you have a function that returns a defined value, or an enum-value. For example, for "abc", return 11

Comment: Are you actually trying to add cases for different strings, or are you just trying to understand how `switch/case` works?

Answer (score 1):

If ever the following switch statement was possible:

```
switch (arg)
{
    case arg.compare("abc1") == 0: cout << "statements the same1";
    break;
    case arg.compare("abc2") == 0: cout << "statements the same2";
    break;
}
```

It would be totally equal to the following if statement (do you want a break statement?):

```
if(arg.compare("abc1") == 0) cout << "statements the same1";
// no break is needed
else if(arg.compare("abc2") == 0) cout << "statements the same2";
// no break is needed
```

Which is really equal to:

```
if(arg.compare("abc1") == 0)
{
    cout << "statements the same1";
}
else if(arg.compare("abc2") == 0)
{
    cout << "statements the same2";
}
```

And it is how if-else statement works exactly the way that you wanted, because it will not check for the next conditions if one of them is true.

Answer (score 1):

If the set of strings is statically known to you (at development time, e.g. because it is a set of known keywords or identifiers) you might want to use a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) generator like [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/)

If coding in C++11 you could also make a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) of anonymous [functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/):

```
  std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string&)> 
   funmap = {
    { "abc", [&](const std::string& name) 
                { std::cout << name; } },
    { "cde", [&](const std::string& name) 
                { do_something_with(name); } },
   };
```

later you would do something like

```
   auto it = funmap.find(somestring);
   if (it != funmap.end()) it->second(somestring);
```